# How do we get the ordinal positions within an index for all items in a list efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the *unique* `pd.Index` `idx` and the list of indices `lst`

```
idx = pd.Index(list('abcdefg'))
lst = list('bdf')
```

We can get the ordinal position of `'b'` by `idx.get_loc('b')`.

How do we get the ordinal positions for all items in `lst` efficiently?

`idx.get_loc(lst)` does not work:

```
TypeError: '['b', 'd', 'f']' is an invalid key
```

Comment: You're admitting you index as unique values, correct? Also what the typical size of your index? Because from your example `[idx.get_loc(item) for item in lst]` is the trivial way to do it

Comment: Yes!  I'll update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx.searchsorted(lst)
```

If `idx` is not sorted, we need to use `sorter` argument with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [317]: timeit (np.array(idx)[:,None]==np.array(lst)).argmax(0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.4 µs per loop
In [318]: timeit [idx.index(i) for i in lst]
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.78 µs per loop
In [321]: timeit np.where(np.in1d(idx,lst))
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.1 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `lst` a numpy array and compare with broadcasting.  Then use `argmax` to identify the positions.

```
(idx.values[:, None] == np.array(lst)).argmax(0)

array([1, 3, 5])
```